# Azure Redis Caching dynamic applicationName or key name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, caching, redis, azure-redis-cache

I am trying to use Azure Redis Cache to store output caching of "Multi Tenant MVC Application". I need somehow a way to differentiate keys stored on Redis server. Look at the screenshot below, notice TenantId_a2/*, here in the key name 'TenantId' I wanted to control programmatically.

[image]

Because i'm using Redis for output caching, i need to configure redis output cache in web.config file, screenshot here:

[image]

There is another way to configure redis cache from application code, but that's not for output caching...i'm sure. That's the code:

```
public class AzureRedisCache
{
    private static Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> lazyConnection = new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(() =>
    {
        string configString = "********";
        var options = ConfigurationOptions.Parse(configString);
        options.ClientName = "TenantId"; // GREAT :)
        options.AllowAdmin = true;
        return ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(options);
    });

    public static ConnectionMultiplexer Connection
    {
        get
        {
            return lazyConnection.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Now to call this, we just use

```
IDatabase cache = AzureRedisCache.Connection.GetDatabase();
```

I'm not sure if any way to use this code for output caching or some other way to achieve said requirement. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this? Would it help if you dynamically set the application name as such? You can put this info your application start logic (application_start)

```
OutputCacheSection ops = (OutputCacheSection)WebConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/caching/outputCache");
        ProviderSettings providerSettings = ops.Providers[0];
        providerSettings.Parameters["applicationName"] = "myDynamicApplicationName";
```

Comment: To clarify, you would put the above code into your app startup logic.  This is not a setting you should change randomly during app execution (e.g. based on inputs from the customer).

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, this looks correct, will update once i try this.

Comment: Is it possible to delete cache from Redis based on applicationName?

Comment: well, its not working, i still see appname which is set in web.config

Comment: @Abhimanyu you need to move this up to Application_Start(). I moved it to the first line in Application_Start() and it worked fine